# phonegap custom plugin for android advice needed

Tags: android, plugins, cordova

Hi I am in mobile app.

I have developed an app in phonegap (html5, JQuery, JS) and I want to develop a plugin to print to a BT printer.

I download printer manufacturer's SDK and I imported the appropriate .jar file to my project with the following way:

To include this library into your project:

1. Drag the appropriate library file into the Project Explorer from the SDK package
2. Right click the project folder and choose Properties
3. Click Java Build Path
4. Click Libraries and the Add JARs button
5. At the top of your main code add:

   import com.starmicronics.stario.StarIOPort;

   import com.starmicronics.stario.StarIOPortException;

   import com.starmicronics.stario.StarPrinterStatus;
6. Now you can access all of StarIO’s methods!

I create the following plugin

js

```
var HelloPlugin = {

    callNativeFunction: function (success, fail, resultType) {
        return cordova.exec(success, fail, "com.tricedesigns.HelloPlugin", "nativeAction", [resultType]);
    }
};
```

java

```
package com.tricedesigns;

import com.starmicronics.stario.StarIOPort;
import com.starmicronics.stario.StarIOPortException;
import com.starmicronics.stario.StarPrinterStatus;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;



public class HelloPlugin extends Plugin {

    public static final String NATIVE_ACTION_STRING="nativeAction";
    public static final String SUCCESS_PARAMETER="success";
    public static final String portName = "BT:";
    public static final String portSettings = "mini";

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray data, String callbackId) {

         Log.d("HelloPlugin", "Hello, this is a native function called from PhoneGap/Cordova!");

         //only perform the action if it is the one that should be invoked
         if (NATIVE_ACTION_STRING.equals(action)) {

             String resultType = null;
             try {
                 resultType = data.getString(0);
             }
             catch (Exception ex) {
                 Log.d("HelloPlugin", ex.toString());
             }

             byte[] texttoprint = resultType.toString().getBytes();

             if (resultType.equals(SUCCESS_PARAMETER)) {

                 StarIOPort port = null;

                 return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "Yay, Success!!!");
             }
             else {
                 return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "Oops, Error :(");
             }
         }

         return null;
    }

}
```

which is working with no promblems.

When i try to include the below call to printer .jar method

```
port = StarIOPort.getPort(portName, portSettings, 10000, context);
```

I get Error: Status=2 Message=Class not found.

Where am i wrong????

Comment: Did you add printer .jar files to phonegap project?

Comment: yes I have added the .jar to project as manufacturer suggest...

Comment: Make sure the printer .jar is in the libs folder so it is automatically added into the Android app.